oauth2-client behind gateway, how to config google oauth2?
I'm coding my app.with structure like that :
1 gateway app (spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc) run on localhost:8080
1 auth app (spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client) run on localhost:8201
when i call oauth2 api login on browser, it seem not working
localhost
host config
google config
link login oauth2 (redirect to auth)
http://localhost:8080/auth/oauth2/authorization/google
error
please help me, how to config, setup oauth2 social login?
